# Timebox property change for an object and then take action

Tags: java, c#, events, flicker

I have a problem that I am unable to crack and I am looking for pointers from you coding genius :)

### Problem

I have an event let's say `Event1` which gets fired when the caller takes certain action for the sake of our problem let's say we need to fire `Event1` whenever the user presses any key on the keyboard or moves the mouse

```
class Event1 {
...
    public Event1(String name) {
    }
}


class Runner {

   public static void main(String arg[]){
      while(true) {
          //User enters some text via command line or moves mouse
          Fire(new Event1("key up"));
      }
   }
   private static Fire(Event1 event){
      //Calls some external api
   }
}
```

If the user is continuously typing, we will end up firing 100s of events per minute. What I want to do is timebox the change i.e. When I detect the user changing the input mechanism from keyboard to mouse or vice versa I fire the event. I am also adding some examples which state when it's ideal to fire the event.

### Example

```
|Event| Keyboard| Mouse   | Keyboard | Mouse   | Keyboard | Keyboard |  Mouse   | Keyboard |
|----| -------- | ------- | -------- | ------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
|Time| 12:00:00 |12:00:01 | 12:00:02 |12:00:03 | 12:00:06 | 12:00:07 | 12:00:09 | 12:00:11 | 
|----| -------- | ------- | -------- | ------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
|Fire| True     | False   | False   | True    | True     | False    | True     | True     |
```

I can keep a track of `prev` event type and decide if the `current` is same then dont fire the event but I am unable to solve the flickering where the input mechanism keeps on changing frequently.

*FYI: I am using Csharp language if that matters :)*

Comment: If it's C#, then why tag Java?

Comment: Also: define "flicker". And: the example is unclear to me. What would trigger and what wouldn't? I don't see a clear pattern.

Comment: I am not looking for exact code examples more like general approach.

Flicker: Instead of firing events as you receive, you would analyse them and then take action. For ex if you receive 4 consecutive events like Keyboard/Mouse/Keyboard/Mouse it would makes sense to jsut fire 2 events (1 for keyboard & another for mouse). I hope this makes sense?

Comment: I still don't understand "flicker". Is this a term you've defined yourself? If you look at the other questions tagged "flicker" on SO you'll see that they concern screen rendering/painting.  Also, if already know how to conditionally NOT fire the event, why can't you also decide when to fire it?